# I'm getting an error when I execute stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am getting the following error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'As BEGIN SELECT count(CustomerFeed.overall) as sat FROM
>   ContactCenter L' at line 2

when I run this statement.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts2(IN location VARCHAR(100),
                                 IN start1   TIMESTAMP,
                                 IN end1     TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
  SELECT count(CustomerFeed.overall) AS sat
  FROM   ContactCenter
         LEFT JOIN CustomerFeed
           ON ContactCenter.callId = CustomerFeed.callId
  WHERE  date(ContactCenter.callClose) BETWEEN start1 AND end1
         AND ContactCenter.callStatus = 'Close'
         AND CustomerFeed.overall IN ( 1, 2 )
         AND ContactCenter.location = location
         AND ContactCenter.gNum != '';
       END //
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: First of all: ***WHAT ERROR???*** We can't see your screen nor read your mind - you have to tell us! Secondly: for what **concrete database** system? SQL is just the query language - used by many databases ....

Comment: you are using **start** and **end** as variable names. Those are keywords in your sql. give another name to it them

Comment: the error is as follows

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'As BEGIN SELECT count(CustomerFeed.overall) as sat FROM ContactCenter L' at line 2

Comment: i am executing this in phpmyadmin

Comment: i changed start and end variable names but still same error

Comment: Then change the question - ppl will think that could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `AS` keyword in a [stored procedure definition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) in MySql. So remove it.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts2(IN location varchar(100),
                                 IN start timestamp,
                                 IN end timestamp)
BEGIN
   ...
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: that was my guess too. but you've said "don't need", which implies it's OK with or without. I suspect it's not OK. just say that

Comment: @user2598065 Do you still get the same error after you removed `AS`?

Comment: @user2598065 Do you care to elaborate on *...but no use...*? `AS` in `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement was the **exact** cause of your original error message. Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e729) demo. And [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e729) example when it compiles without errors. You most probably now have a problem with your query.

Comment: @Bohemian Fair enough. Thanks for input. Rephrased the answer.

Comment: @namratha Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?